# Overlow on R trying to compute a big integer

Tags: r, overflow

I am encountering a R problem. I was simply trying to make the sum of all the different values in a column from a big data set. Code looks like that:

```
sum(Animal$Pigs, na.rm = TRUE)
```

However R tells me:

```
In sum(Animal$Pigs, na.rm = TRUE) :
  integer overflow - use sum(as.numeric(.))
```

Does it mean that the resulting integer is too big ? Are there any packages that might help ? If not, is there another language I could turn to for large data set (I know a bit of python).

Comment: Why not just do as the message suggests?  Integers in R are 32 bits, while doubles can store all 53 bit integers exactly.

Comment: I remember having a couple of problems with some value sur as.numeric in the past, and as there are so many data to sum, I will not have a way to verify. 

Therefore if I can avoid as.numeric I would rather do so.

Comment: If they are non-negative numbers, just test `sum < 2^53`.  If that's true, it's exact.  Mixed signs are harder, though you could use the same test twice, once on the positives and once on the abs value of the sum of the negatives.

Answer (score 0):

The manual of `sum` says:

> Integer overflow should no longer happen since R version 3.5.0.

To *calculate with large integer numbers* you can use the `gmp` library.

```
sum(10L^100L, 10L^50L, 1L)
#[1] 1e+100

library(gmp)
sum.bigz(as.bigz("10")^100L, as.bigz("10")^50L, 1)
#[1] 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
```

Comment: Thanl you,

I tried to install gmp package & library(gmp) but neither works. Any idea why ?

Comment: I just forgot the "" I am an idiot :3. Thank you for your help !

Comment: Unfortunately gmp does not seem to solve the issue.

Comment: @Menan Why not?

Comment: I do not understand why but I still get the same overflow error message. I will try to look at it in detail tomorrow to make sure I did not made any mistake.

Thank you for your help anyway !

Comment: I finally managed I was stuck because of assuming that the gmp packages was overriding the basic sum function. Thank you for your help :)